# lintOptions deprecated , What is the alternative?

Tags: android, android-lint, android-gradle-plugin-7.4

I have upgraded Android Gradle Plugin to `7.4`.

Now getting warning [`lintOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions) are deprecated.

[image: lintOption Deprecated]

What alternative is to be used for this?

Answer (score 4):

We can use the new [`Lint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint) block.

The old [`lintOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions) block is deprecated in Android Gradle Plugin `7.2` and replaced by the new [`Lint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint) block. We can simply replace it and use it in the app-level `build.gradle` file like the below example.

**Groovey Example:**

```
lint {
    disable 'MissingTranslation', 'TypographyFractions'
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

**Kotlin DSL Example:**

```
lint {
    disable += "MissingTranslation" + "TypographyFractions"
    abortOnError = false
    checkReleaseBuilds =  false
}
```

Most of the properties are the same as previously but you can check [Summary](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint#summary),  [Public properties](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint#public-properties_1), and [Configure lint options with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#gradle).

Comment: `  
 lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        abortOnError = false
    }`


if you are using build.gradle.kts

Comment: @adonese , Thanks. I have updated the answer accordingly.